# Using arrayformula() like continue with nested if()

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

My goal is to fill down formula while data exist in an adjacent column.

Here is my original formula:

```
=index(lookups!$M$2:$M30,match($A3,lookups!$N$2:$N30,0))
```

This formula works in that results are returned as expected.

I then tried this in the hope of it copying down:

```
=index(lookups!$M$2:$M30,match($A3:A,lookups!$N$2:$N30,0))
```

This resulted in #N/A "Did not find value in match"

Then I read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/260527/how-to-create-a-formula-for-every-row-in-a-column-in-google-spreadsheet) post and looked at the second most voted answer and tried editing my formula to this:

```
=arrayFormula(index(lookups!$M$2:$M30,match($A3:A,lookups!$N$2:$N30,0)))
```

This time the formula copy down as I hoped, but with a #VALUE error "Function IF parameter 1 expects boolean values. But 'ADT- Alaska Travel Vendor Activities (Search)' is a text and cannot be coerced to a boolean."

How can I tell sheets to copy the index(Match()) all the way down while data exist in column A?

Comment: Looks like a VLOOKUP may be better here. Can you share a sample spreadsheet with the expected outcome ?

Comment: I don;t think Vlookup will work here? "Lookup" is just the name of a tab I have which contains a lookup table. I'll edit the formula as if the lookup table was on same sheet.

Comment: You can let me try if by providing a sample spreadsheet ?

Comment: Hi cloned editable sheet here, any help appreciated: https://docs.google.com/a/envoke.com/spreadsheets/d/1wwimx1IC1eQ9FZpY2ytuVWCLDBnJPPDp8UxV6A_Brvk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The sheet is not accessible. Can you fix the permissions ?

Comment: Woops sorry about that. Try this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kbXumLg_6Vwz-rnFk2vEGAdibEsrea3mL9ZafbQ_8pg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this formula delivers the desired output ?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(vlookup(A3:A, {lookups!$B$2:$B, lookups!$A$2:$A}, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: It does indeed! Thank you so much? Could you tell me what's going on here? Why curly braces?

Comment: Sure. The curly braces are creating and new array (table), 2 columns wide with the first column being the B-column and the second column the A-column of the sheet 'lookups'. This is done because then we can use vlookup that expects matches in the first column. Then we retrieve the second column (witch is in fact the A-column) and wrap the vlookup in arrayformula to array-enable it.  Hope that makes sense ?

Comment: It does thank you once again. So vlookup() works with array formula but index(match()) does not?